# How to disable the selection column in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to hide the selection column (I don't know what it is said so just saying selection column) as shown in the figure...[image: DataGridView]

Also say me what exact this column said...

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Set [`RowHeadersVisible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheadersvisible(v=vs.110).aspx) to false

Comment: Done, thanx :) @RezaAghaei

Comment: Yes it is duplicate of your link but I just now got to know that it is called row Header and I was searching a different name of that as I described in description.... So now Should I delete this post??? @Breeze

Comment: @RitaShroff no, the question might be helpful to others, so don't delete it. It would be great if you could flag it as a duplicate yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Please set `RowHeadersVisible = false` and you can achieve what you want.